# org.json.JSONException: Find specific string from Json Object

Tags: android, json

I am working in `Android` and finding `json` from internet that looks like this:

```
JSONObject childObject=me.getJSONObject(pos);
String fisrtkey=childObject.getString("A");
JSONArray jsonArray=childObject.getJSONArray("c");
```

I want to find `C21` that is in the `A`. See the `json` coming from request.
Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the value of `item` in the loop?

Comment: Invalid JSON ... copy and paste json on jsonlint.com and check its validity

Comment: @TimCastelijns The program is even not finding `me` giving exception `org.json.JSONException: No value for me`

Comment: If you just want to find out the string in json, why dont you use simple method java.lang.String.contains() and used it to check is it existed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
        JSONObject j=new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray c= null;
        c = j.getJSONArray("This");
        JSONObject item=c.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray me=item.getJSONArray("me");

        for(int pos=0;pos<me.length();pos++)
        {

            JSONObject childObject=me.getJSONObject(pos);
            String fisrtkey=childObject.getString("A");
            JSONArray jsonArray=childObject.getJSONArray("c");
        }



    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

//hope this will help you and also check json is invalid or not ,you missed 
     // bracket of jsonarray "me".

Comment: You gave me the direction. It was not bracket problem. It was y concept problem. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed **THIS** json array while parsing. First get that and from that json object and then get **ME** json array. Something like this

```
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONArray c = j.getJSONArray("This");
    JSONObject j1 = c.getJSONArray(0);
    JSONArray d = j.getJSONArray("me");
    for(int n = 0; n < c.length(); n++) {
        JSONObject item = c.getJSONObject(n);
        System.out.println(item.getString("A"));
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray c = j.getJSONArray("me");
for(int n = 0; n < c.length(); n++) {
    JSONObject person = (JSONObject) c.get(n );
    String id = person.getString("A"); 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference

Comment: @Anantham it is giving exception `org.json.JSONException: No value for me`

Comment: can you post full code for your parsing,bcz wher you parse "this" json array,inside the we have "me " @waqas